# Good default for XDG_RUNTIME_DIR?

Tags: directory, desktop, defaults

The [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) is a very interesting spec for user directories. It also provides good default values, except for `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`.

Now I am writing a software that needs to create named pipes. It is a per-user client-server framework (there is a FIFO for the server and a FIFO per client).

If `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is not defined, I am currently using a per-user subdirectory in `/tmp` — but it does not ensure all the specified conditions (viz. the paragraph starting with *"The lifetime of the directory MUST be bound to the user being logged in…"*)

Is `/tmp/myserver-$USER` good enough?

**Edit**

I saw elsewhere a few suggestions:

- `.` is quite unsatisfactory (at least because it is not an absolute path).
- I also saw `/var/run/user/$USER` — not bad, but that directory does not exist (at least on my box running a Debian *testing*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/tmp` is used by plenty of programs in a similar way already. On my system I can see the `/tmp/orbit-$USER` (used by Gnome's ORBit2) and `/tmp/.X11-unix/` (Xorg and X11) directories with plenty of pipes, ehm, sockets, in them. I am sure there are also others, so I see nothing wrong with what you are doing. Just be prepared that since it is a world writeable location a malicious process can hijack the location (verify the permissions before you write to it).

I can also recommend `$TMPDIR` for those who use [pam_mktemp](http://www.openwall.com/pam/), as this directory is only accessible by the user.

Comment: PAM is the right solution, thanks! On Debian it is called libpam-tmpdir

Answer (score 11):

SystemD makes `/run/user/$UID` kinda mandatory.

http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html

> Unprivileged Write Access
>
> Unprivileged processes generally lack write access to most of the
> hierarchy.
>
> The exceptions for normal users are `/tmp`, `/var/tmp`, `/dev/shm`, as well
> as the home directory `$HOME` (usually found below `/home`) and **the
> runtime directory *`$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`* (found below `/run/user`)** of the
> user, which are all writable.
>
> For unprivileged system processes only `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` and `/dev/shm` are
> writable. If an unprivileged system process needs a private, writable
> directory in `/var` or `/run`, it is recommended to either create it
> before dropping privileges in the daemon code, to create it via
> tmpfiles.d(5) fragments during boot, or via the `RuntimeDirectory=`
> directive of service units (see systemd.unit(5) for details).

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/pam_systemd.html

> If it does not exist yet, the user runtime directory `/run/user/$UID` is either created or mounted as new "`tmpfs`" file system with quota applied, and its ownership changed to the user that is logging in.

Comment: `/run/user/${USER}` on my machine means `/run/user/mazunki`, while systemd uses `/run/user/1000` on all the machines I've seen, and I am pretty sure this is the norm. There is `/run/user/${UID}`, or the better `/run/user/$(id -u)`. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @mazunki

Answer (score 4):

Create directory /tmp/service-$USER.id with unique id. For exsmple, in shell:

```
mktemp -d /tmp/service-"$USER".XXX
```

Comment: How do you ensure the requirement that the same directory is used from the first login to the last logout of the user?

Comment: Hmmm... create symlink ~user/.service/tmp_dir. If linked directory does not exist, create new

Comment: `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=$(ls -d /tmp/service-$USER.???* 2>/dev/null || mktemp -d /tmp/service-$USER.XXX | tee >(xargs chmod 0700))`

Comment: @RyanLue Cool stuff, using `$TMPDIR` instead of `/tmp` seems to make commands compatible with macOS. Problem is just, this will not remove the directory when all sessions are terminated, thus it doesn't follow the implementation fully as necessary.